# django - differentiate users in the template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

So, I am trying to create a user page, and its url will be associated with its username, something like this

> http://domain.com/accounts/profile/robin/

And in that page, I want all the photo's uploaded by that user (here 'robin') to be displayed in the template. And another thing is, in the menu bar, there's an link for the the profile page for the request.user, i.e. the logged in user, suppose the user is 'kevin', and it will also direct it to the request.user's url like:

> http://domain.com/accounts/profile/kevin/

Somehow I managed to get the desired output. But what I also wanted was that, even if I change the url to something different other than the request.user's name, I wanted the request.user and the other username to be differentiated easily, so that I can manipulate them in the templates. And so I hopefully came with this solution.

But I really don't know that this is an appropriate solution. Because what if I change the username to something other than the request.user and come up with all its information. Is there a better way to do it?

test.html:

```
<body>

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/photo/">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="/accounts/profile/{{user_1}}/">{{user_1.username}}</a></li>
            </ul>   
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </body>
```

profile_page.html:

```
{% extends 'test.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>{{user.username}}</p>

<div id="container">
{% for photo in photos %}
<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.image}}" width="300px" />
{% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
 class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="creator_set")
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, through="Like")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Photos')

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

app's urls.py:

```
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'userprofile.views.profile_page'),
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def profile_page(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_1 = request.user
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        user_photos = user.creator_set.all()
        return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {'user':user,'photos':user_photos, 'user_1':user_1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing `request.user` as `user_1` and user to show profile as `user` do it other way around. In template you already get `user` variable for the logged in user and doing the request.

I would update the view as:

```
@login_required
def profile_page(request, username):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        #no need for user, photos
        user_1 = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return render(request, 'profile_page.html', {'user_1':user_1})
```

Also, you don't need to pass list of photos, you can do that in template itself.
So update template as:

```
{% extends 'test.html' %}

{% block content %}
<p>{{user_1.username}}</p>

<div id="container">
    {% for photo in user_1.creater_set.all %}
        <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{photo.image}}" width="300px" />
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Change a block in test.html as

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="/photo/">Photos</a></li>
    {#here you can use name of the pattern as well instead of view #}
    <li><a href="{% url 'userprofile.views.profile_page' user.username%}">             
             {{user.username}} </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, I updated the view as yours, just I changed `user_1` to `user_profile`. And with user.username I can access the logged in user's profile as you told. Just, one more question though. When I try request.user.username, why does it gives me an error, `NoReverseMatch at /accounts/profile/pica/ Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found`.???

Comment: @Robin, in template don't use `request.user...` but use `user.username`

Comment: Is request.user depereciated? When can I use it then?

Comment: @Robin, for that you need to add `context_processors.request` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `request.user` directly in Django templates, you don't need to set `user_1`, for example:

```
<li><a href="/accounts/profile/{{request.user}}/">{{request.user.username}}</a></li>
```

would work just fine.

Secondly, the preferred way to get that URL (which would avoid any issues if you changed where it is later) would be to provide a name for the urlpattern, like this:

```
url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'userprofile.views.profile_page', name='profile'),
```

then use the `url` tag in the template:

```
<li><a href="{% url 'profile' username=request.user.username %}">{{request.user.username}}</a></li>
```

And then it'll always get the right URL, even if you changed the urlpattern later.

Comment: Ok, I changed my views.py and and url:
`url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'userprofile.views.profile_page', name='profile'),`.
And in the templates I changed it like this:
`<li><a href="{% url 'profile' request.user.username %}">{{request.user.username}}</a></li>`
But when I try to access the url for something like this:
`http://localhost:8000/accounts/profile/pica/`.
I get an error:
`NoReverseMatch at /accounts/profile/pica/
Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`. What am I doing wrong?